# how can i avoid including repeatedly or abstract header & footer angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, routes, angular-ui-router

```
 var headerView = {
  templateUrl: 'views/header/header.html',
  controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
 };

var footerView = {
  templateUrl: 'views/footer/footer.html'
};
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

        myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});

        myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            // default route
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            // ui router states
            $stateProvider
                .state('first', {
                    url: "/first",
                    views: {
                        header: headerView,
                        content: {
                            template: '<p>First content</>',
                            controller: function($scope) {}
                        },
                        footer: footerView
                    }
                })
                .state('second', {
                    url: "/second",
                    views: {
                        header: headerView,
                        content: {
                            template: '<p>Second content</>',
                            controller: function($scope) {}
                        },
                        footer: footerView
                    }
                });

        });
```

in above code repeatedly including header and footer  so i would like to avoid including repeatedly header and footer . how can i avoid including repeatedly or  abstract this header and footer, i am using node, web-pack, ui-router ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add header and footer in the master template, outside the scope of MainCtrl controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have a abstract state that will have your header and footer template, and mid section will be act as placeholder for your `main` view, that will be change based on your URL.

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
   <ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
   <ui-view name="content"></ui-view>
   <ui-view name="footer"></ui-view>
</div>
```

**State**

```
$stateProvider
.state('root', {
  url: "/",
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    header: headerView,
    footer: footerView
  }
})
.state('root.first', {
  url: "first",
  views: {
    content: {
      template: '<p>First content</>',
      controller: function($scope) {}
    }
  }
})
.state('root.second', {
  url: "second",
  views: {
    content: {
      template: '<p>Second content</>',
      controller: function($scope) {}
    }
  }
});
```

So speaking in terms of states, you have `root` as parent state. And `first`,`second` & other will be child state of your `root` apparently shares common `header` & `footer`. Also we declared `root` state as `abstract`, because no one can use(navigate to) abstract state.

Comment: i did try above code header and footers are not rendering content only render